# Dojo dStore Rest dGrid sort parameter

Tags: dojo, dgrid, dstore

When I fetch from a dStore the URL looks something like this

```
http://localhost/rest/dojo?department=sales
```

which works fine. If I then click in the header of the dGrid the sent URL looks like this.

```
http://localhost/rest/dojo?department=sales&sort(+id)&limit(25)
```

Shouldn't it send &sort=+id&limit=25? I am using Java and Spring for the backend and it expects the parameters to be formatted this way. Right now I can not receive the extra parameters. Is there a way to get it to send the parameters the way Spring is expecting them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sort(...)` and `limit(...)` are the default behaviors of `dstore/Request` (which `Rest` extends), but these can be customized via `sortParam` for sort, and `useRangeHeaders` or `rangeStartParam` and `rangeCountParam` for range.

For example, to result in `&sort=+id&limit=25` as you requested, you could set up your store as follows:

```
var store = new Rest({
    target: '...',
    sortParam: 'sort',
    rangeStartParam: 'offset',
    rangeCountParam: 'limit'
});
```

I've additionally assumed above that `offset` is the GET parameter you'd want to use to indicate what record to start at when requesting ranges.  Generally if you're not using range headers (`useRangeHeaders` defaults to `false`) and you want to set a count GET parameter, you'll also need to set a start GET parameter.

These properties are listed in the [Request Store documentation](https://github.com/SitePen/dstore/blob/1.1/docs/Stores.md#request).

Comment: I'm not positive but I don't think this answers my question. The parameters do include "sort" and "limit" that's not this issue. My problem is the format of the URL. There 's no "=" between the parameters and the values. See the second URL above. It currently sends "sort(+id)" and not "sort=+id".

Comment: I suppose I could've been more clear about the default behaviors of `Request`, which are to use `sort(...)` and `limit(...)` if none of the `Param` properties are set.  Once you use the `Param` properties, `Request` changes its behavior to sending standard key/value pairs, using the `Param` property settings as the keys.  Give it a try.

Comment: This does seem confusing to me though. I would think the default format would be the way I described it. I have never seen it done the other way. Also by specifying the sortParam I would expect that to change the name of the param only. There is no indication that the format will also change by specifying a name.